# Refs - one 'ref' few objects

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm just wondering... is I'll define one 'ref' in a controller and will have few objects matching criteria for this 'ref', will I be able to retrieve both with the 'getter' method?

as an example the code below (Controller):

```
Ext.define('aBMin.controller.EmailRead', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

config : {
    control : {
        emailViewSubmit : {
            tap : 'funEmailViewSubmit'
        },
        emailViewSubmitCreateTicket : {
            tap : 'funEmailViewSubmitCreateTicket'
        }
    },
    refs : {
        emailViewPanel : 'emailread-panel'
        ,ticketViewPanel : {
            selector : 'ticketview-panel',
            xtype : 'ticketview-panel',
            autoCreate : true
        }
        ,dashboardPanel : 'dashboard-panel'
        ,emailViewSubmit : 'button[action="emailViewSubmit"]'
        ,emailViewSubmitCreateTicket : 'button[action="emailViewSubmitCreateTicket"]'
        ,ticktViewStaff : 'selectfield[alias=ticketview-supportstaffid]'
        ,ticketViewSubmit : 'button[action="ticketViewSubmit"]'
        ,emailBody : 'displayfield[name="emailbody"]'
    }
```

View (take a note - 2 buttons with the same action = emailViewSubmitCreateTicket):

```
items : [{
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Create Ticket',
            action : 'emailViewSubmitCreateTicket',
            ui : 'confirm',
            width : '100%',
            hidden : true,
            margin : '0 0 2px'
        }, {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Save',
            action : 'emailViewSubmit',
            ui : 'confirm',
            width : '100%',
            margin : '0 0 2px'          
        }, {
            xtype : 'button',
            text : 'Create Ticket',
            action : 'emailViewSubmitCreateTicket',
            ui : 'confirm',
            width : '100%',
            hidden : true,
            margin : '0 0 2px'
        }
```

and by the 'getter' function I mean for ex.

```
glob.getEmailViewSubmitCreateTicket().setHidden(false);
```

will this affect both of them or just one? As I've tested - this will affect only one. Any ideas how to do the same but, what I want is to affect 2 buttons at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refs can only return one instance which is the first that is found. If you need to get all instances use the `Ext.ComponentQuery` which is internally used anyway.

Sort of this should do it

```
Ext.Array.each(
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[action=emailViewSubmitCreateTicket]'), 
        function(item){
            item.setHidden(false);
    });
```

Comment: Thanx, I'll go with this solution, refs are more elegant thaugh.